# Yii2 Modal: How to change/disable layout in a Modal windows?

Tags: layout, yii, yii2, bootstrap-modal

When you load a view in a Modal window, the view's controller's action doesn't execute. So, any code you put in there is never executed. How can i change the layout in a modal window?

I tried puting `Yii::$app->controller->layout = 'popup.php';` **in the view loaded in a modal**, but don't. The main layout still remains in a modal window.

Also, i've tried using `Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('myUpdate', ...);` **in the update view loaded that call the _form in cuestion in a modal**, but no way. The main layout still remains in a modal window.

So... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, renderAjax() was the solution. 
Thanks to me.